# How to enable mouse scrolling zoom and dragging on images shown by cv2.imshow

Tags: qt, opencv

When installing opencv on my terminal using

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

I am able to show an image with `cv2.imshow` and can zoom in with the mouse wheel and drag to move around the image. However, in my virtual environment on pycharm, I used the git repositories for opencv to build it due to needing to use the nonfree modules of opencv (to use SIFT, SURF, and FAST). However, when using

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/<username>/tracking/venv \
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../opencv_contrib/modules \
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON \
-D PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=/home/<username>/tracking/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages \
-D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON ../opencv


make -j8


sudo make install
```

I can no longer zoom in and drag around the image with my mouse when showing an image with `cv2.imshow`. Is there a specific change I have to make when building opencv to be able to do this?

For context, this is how I have the repositories and build folder:

```
opencv_build/
├── build
├── opencv
├── opencv_contrib
└── opencv-python
```

Here are examples of what I see in the pip version and wish to see in the compiled version:

This is how it looks right after opening with `cv2.imshow`:
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ere7.png)

This is how it looks after zooming in a bit (note that I am also able to drag the mouse and look around the zoomed in image):
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMZ8N.png)

After zooming in a lot this is what the image looks like (with the RGB values visible):
[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6I7su.png)

Comment: When you compile opencv with Qt you will get such features in the oprncv windows.

Comment: You mean the upper window right? https://answers.opencv.org/upfiles/13494575762997644.jpg

Comment: Not really. I mean that when I do `cv2.imshow(img_name)`  a window shows up that is just the image. However, when opencv was installed from `pip install opencv-contrib-python` I am able to hover the mouse over the image and if scroll I can zoom in, and if I click when zoomed in, I can drag around the image. But when I compile opencv and click on the window for the image, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: In the pip version, is there are bar with buttons (zoom etc.) at the top of the window? Then you will have to compile opencv with Qt support to get those features. Can you make a screenshot of an imshow window in your pip installed version?

Comment: I updated the post to show the images of what the pip version looks like. There isn't really a bar or any buttons, the difference is simply the ability to zoom in with the mouse, drag around, and being able to see the RGB values

Comment: At the bottom of the window you can see the x, y, rgb info, which looks like in the Qt window from my image.

Comment: Okay let me try it.

Comment: It worked! It does not look the exact same as the pip version since there is that tool bar at the top but that is irrelevant. If anything, this has more features than the pip version. It works exactly as I wanted. Thanks!